# Open Source iPhone Games

Tags: ios, sparrow-framework

I'm starting to learn iOS Game Development. I was wondering if any of you knew of any Open Source Projects built on the Sparrow Framework? (http://www.sparrow-framework.org) I've looked at cocos2d project and it all way to much for me right now. The Sparrow Framework is easier to understand. IF you wouldn't mind pointing me into tutorials and open source projects, i'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: You may have better luck at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ -- the focus there is more specifically game development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the iPhone open source game using the Sparrow Framework.

I just give you an example game using the Cocos2d.

http://code.google.com/p/mintgostop/

This is the iPhone open source game, Korean Traditional card game.

Answer (score 0):

Canabalt is open source http://blog.semisecretsoftware.com/nearly-25000-raised-for-charity-canabalt-goes